# Devise & Custom Rails User URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am currently using Rails 3.2.5 with the latest devise gem.

Currently users can access their profile page at...
example.com/users/john-doe

I want to remove the users portion of the url, so the url would be *example.com/john-doe*.  Is this possible with devise?

Right now in my routes file I have the following...

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a route for it. You will probably want it to be the last one in the routes file.

Something like:

```
match '/:user' => "users#show", :as => :user_profile
```

Comment: Thanks this gets me almost completely there, just need the user_path to use this route.  Digging through routing documentation...

Comment: You may want to use the :as option. For example :as => :user_profile will give you a handy user_profile_path helper.

Comment: yes this works, i should have checked SO you were 5 minutes faster than me finding the :as option :)  thanks again.