# Understanding what's going on with : and # in ruby, rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, devise, routes, symbols

In the answer to this question about routes in Devise: [Devise & Custom Rails User URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909319/devise-custom-rails-user-urls)
There is a line of code:

```
match '/:user' => "users#show", :as => :user_profile
```

That apparently works for the question asker, but not for me. I end up with

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#show
undefined method `books' for nil:NilClass
```

when I go to localhost:3000/*username* instead of localhost:3000/user/*username*. I assume because the *match* line above isn't working correctly and that url does not refer to any user, according to my routes file.

The second url routes me to the user's *show* page, but I don't want the extra */user* in the url.

So I'm trying to figure out exactly what *'/:user'*, *:as*, and *:user_profile* mean because I think I'm supposed to substitute a few things here specific to my app. I think *:as* is some kind of aliased method. I can't find anything in the Devise documentation about a route called *user_profile*. And I don't know what *'/:user'* is referring to. An instance of the User object? A user attribute/unique column in my database that I use to refer to specific users? (I use *permalink* for my user-defined urls).

Comment: Please post your routes.rb file, as well as your UsersController.

Comment: The problem is that I was using {match '/:permalink' => "users#show", :as => :user_profile} instead of {match '/:id' => "users#show", :as => :user_profile}. So, at least it works, but unfortunately I wouldn't be able to explain to anyone *why* it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route is working for you. Thats why ur getting error `from users_controller#show`.

In your show action you must be doing something like User.where(:id => params[:id]). But in this case, the attribute in your params is called `:user` . So to make make both routes work, without any change in the show action, change the route to

```
match '/:id' => "users#show", :as => :user_profile
```

Comment: THAT'S IT! Silly me, I was using {match '/:permalink' => "users#show", :as => :user_profile}. Don't know why I didn't try {:id}.

Answer (score 1):

Devise documentation won't refer to a 'user_profile' because it is a custom route being used to help address the issue that the questioner (in the linked question) was asking.

`match '/:user' => "users#show"` means "match any route with a single parameter after `/` that doesn't match a previously defined route, pair this route to the UsersController 'show' action (passing along the singe parameter as 'user')"

Modifying a route using `:as => :anything` will provide several helper methods to refer to this route that may be used in controllers, views, and mailers (in this case `anything_path` and `anything_url`).

As far as why this won't work for you, this is likely do to a problem with this entry in regard to the rest of your routes or because of your controller action itself.  Posting these can help someone track down the exact reason...

Comment: Thanks! I thought that user_profile was a route I was supposed to make up, as opposed to something Devise provided, but I wasn't sure.